# Is there a way to fix SD card drive sizes?

Tags: windows

So I recently reset my PC, and I used a SDXC to USB converter and installed windows on it. I did stuff in the BIOS and now my PC finally reset. So that's good. But now, I formatted the SDXC card and it's a 128 GB drive, but on my device it says 31.9 GB. Before I formatted it It still said 128 GB, but now I'm totally confused on why this happened. If anyone knows how to change the number back to 128 GB, or undo what I did to my drive? Maybe I'm just dumb... (Also I'm on windows so Please don't give me a mac answer ;-;)(Also this is my first question so please don't criticize)

Comment: Have you tried googling this issue? Have you found anything useful? If yes, where did you get stuck?

Comment: How did you format it? Did you try the diskpart "clean" command before formatting it?